# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: freemarker.template.TemplateHashModelEx

Tags: spring, web, freemarker

My application is a servlet, spring 4  application where the spring jar is in the tomcat lib.
Freemarker jar is in WEB-INF/lib.

I am getting this error when starting the server
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: freemarker.template.TemplateHashModelEx

This error disappears when I move the freemarker jar to tomcat lib directory.

It appears to me that spring 4 webmvc jar which contains Configurer class is unable to see WEB-INF/lib freemarker jar. I do not understand why freemarker jar in WEB-INF/lib folder is not visible to spring jar in tomcat lib folder.

What may I do to resolve this situation.
My spring configuration is as follows

```
<bean id="freemarkerConfiguration" class="org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean">
<!--Turn this off to always load via SpringTemplateLoader-->
    <property name="preferFileSystemAccess" value="false"></property>
    <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="classpath:/"></property>
</bean> 

<bean id="freemarkerConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
    <property name="configuration" ref="freemarkerConfiguration" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I've had similar issues before and what I did was to also right-click my project and configure build path and find and add as an external jar. If your not using Maven or another build-tool you should try this.

Comment: I am using maven as my build tool.

Comment: Anyone else has any ideas on how my spring context is broken when freemarker jar is in web-inf/lib and spring-web jar in tomcat/lib?

Answer (score 1):

add the following code in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
    <artifactId>freemarker-gae</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.18</version>
</dependency>
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues before and I've solved it.
Environment：Idea 、 Maven

1. Open File->Project Structure->Artifacts
2. Right click on the Project Library in the "Available Elements" to put in output root(WEB-INF/lib).
3. Restart tomcat and you'll see the problem was solved.

Comment: So essentially, you are asking to put all the framework jars in WEB-INF/lib. It works when all the jars are either in tomcat/lib or when all the jars are in /WEB-INF/lib. It does not work when some jars are in tomcat/lib and some are in WEB-INF/lib. is there a classloader mechanism I need to understand?